# Combine consecutive epoch-periods in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a list of tuples which represent timeslots (start_epoch, end_epoch). What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

If have this list:

```
[
    (1398932511, 1398932991),
    (1398933052, 1398933142),
    (1400018571, 1400020941),
    (1400020941, 1400024572),
    (1400024572, 1400027541),
    (1400027602, 1400028172),
    (1400824012, 1400824162)
]
```

I want the tuples which are consecutive to be joined together in a new list. So the result would be this:

```
[
    (1398932511, 1398932991),
    (1398933052, 1398933142),
    (1400018571, 1400027541),
    (1400027602, 1400028172),
    (1400824012, 1400824162)
]
```

I have been looking around (stackoverflow, Google) but I'm unable to find a proper solution to this. I can't figure out how to properly use itertools for python (I'm fairly new to Python :) ).

Comment: I can't see the difference between the 1st and the 2nd list.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski: the elements `(1400018571, 1400020941), (1400020941, 1400024572), (1400024572, 1400027541)` have been merged into `(1400018571, 1400027541)`.

Comment: Are your ranges always sorted? Or could they be out of order?

Comment: The ranges are always sorted

Comment: Okay, now that the lists are better formatted, it is clear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters kind of disagree with the dupe, unfortunately.  His input is already sorted, his interval boundaries match exactly, and (probably most importantly) none of the answers to that question are particularly good.

Comment: @roippi: It doesn't matter here that the boundaries match or overlap, the accepted answer works for either case. If you feel you can write a better answer, then do so for that question; its still a dupe.

Comment: On reflection, that's probably the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I didn't find the duplicate. Probably used the wrong search.

Comment: 1 more thing. When I posted the question, i saw that the indentation for the code block didn't work (I did use 4 spaces, but it didn't work). Before I could figure out what went wrong, somebody allready edited my question (I believe it was @MartijnPieters). How is a newby like myself going to learn how to post questions properly?

Comment: I only meant to help there, @Fabian. You can use the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) if you wanted to practice your post formatting skills, but I find the preview to work just fine. Hopefully my formatting changes can help you learn? Badly formatted questions can hurt how they are received which is why experienced users edit new posts into shape.

Comment: I know and thank you all for the help. I didn't know about a formatting sandbox. I will be practicing there. Tnx!